# LibreOffice command line (soffice) print options

Tags: linux, printing, terminal, libreoffice

Are there any options for print command via command line?

For e.g. if I want just to print the document from terminal I should use ths command: `soffice -p document.docx`

But is it possible to set some printing optinos for `-p` command if I want two-sided printing or if I want to print pages from this document selectively?

Answer (score 0):

Found out there is no option for this purpose. Only lpr options can be used https://www.cups.org/doc/options.html